# How to write a tryCatch function for survival analysis that includes variable number of covariates?

Tags: r, try-catch, survival-analysis

I am running a cox proportional hazard model that repeats over 20,000 times (given a calculation from different gene combinations). When I run it for a few hundred or thousand, I get no errors. However, given sheer probability, some of the genes end up with (I presume) perfect separation which prevent convergence and produces this warning

```
Warning message:
In coxph.fit(X, Y, istrat, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  ... :
  Loglik converged before variable  1 ; coefficient may be infinite.
```

This kills the function. As such, I would like to make a tryCatch to fix my issue, so that the the results of this coxph would simply be a table of NAs (of the same dimensions as the usual output).

```
**Sample DF**
time - in days
status - censored(0), failed(1)
A,B,C - covariables

time    status    A    B    C
134       0       4    5    12  
324       0       32   3    2   
93        1       4    23   54
23        1       65   9    3
```

This is what I have tried:

```
**original coxph() in the model**
results <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ A + B + C, data=data)


**tryCatch version of coxph()**
coxph.conv = function(time, status, preds, data) {
  tryCatch(
    coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ paste0(preds, collapse="+"), data=data),
    warning = function(w) NA)
}

results <- coxph.conv(time, status, preds=c("A", "B", "C"), data=cox_df)
```

The error I receive when I try to run this is

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ paste0(preds,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'paste0(preds, collapse = "+")')
```

How can I write this tryCatch function so that I can add a variable number of covariables with a + in between them?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is coming from the formula given the `coxph` function.
Try something like the one below to make your formula and then pass it to the coxph function inside `coxph.conv` function.

```
my_formula <- paste0("Surv(", time, " , " status,") ~ ", paste0(preds, collapse =" + "))
```

That is,

```
coxph.conv = function(time, status, preds, data) {

   my_formula <- paste0("Surv(", time, " , ", status,") ~ ", paste0(preds, collapse =" + "))

   # As suggested in comments by @IRTFM, you may need the following line
   my_formula <- as.formula(my_formula)

  tryCatch(
    coxph(my_formula, data=data), warning = function(w) NA)
}
```

Comment: Generally one would need to wrap as.formula around a text object to get a formula, but maybe coxph will coerce to formula? I could see advantages to such a strategy because it will then ensure that the environment for the formula would be correct, but it's not typical of package authors in R to do that. Did you actually test you guess?

Comment: @IRTFM I tested with `lm`; it coerce the string to formula. I have not tested with `coxph`. I should have added ` as.formula` instead of guessing it would work for `coxph` as well.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if you could use `substitute` instead of `paste`?